# Which Vaishnavite sects claim all Gods in Rig Veda refer ultimately to Vishnu and what are their arguments?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, rig-veda

I have seen these arguments in bits and pieces and nothing makes sense. Additionally, how do they reconcile their arguments in the context of Brahma Vaivarta Purana which says Vishnu, Narayana, Siva et al are incarnations of Krishna?

Comment: Can you give any links to the claims?

Comment: All of them, that's one of the primary reasons why they are referred to as Vaishnavas.

Comment: If all of them, then that should form part of the answer. The edits are unnecessary.

Comment: How come you think its wise to ask this question? Isn't this flarring up sectarian rivalry? I thought this is why you downvote my questions.

Comment: @moonstar ***What is a comment?*** Comments exist so that users can talk about questions and answers without posting new answers that do not make an attempt to answer the question asked. Comments are often used to ask for clarification on, suggest corrections to, and provide meta-information about posts.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan The comment by itself is fine. Editing the Q because of the reason mentioned in the comment, is not IMO.

Comment: @moonstar Please read the whole edit history. In any case, the comment was independent of the edit.